# Using the cytoscape-qtip plugin in Aurelia bundler

Tags: aurelia, cytoscape.js

I'm using the aurelia bundler for my project, and I'd like to use cytoscape.js to draw a graph.

I can add the cytoscape main library quite easily with npm (`"cytoscape": "^3.0.0"`) and

```
      {
        "name": "cytoscape",
        "path": "../node_modules/cytoscape/dist",
        "main": "cytoscape.min"
      },
```

in build -> bundles -> dependencies in aurelia.json. Using this setup, I can create a basic graph that works.

However, adding the [qtip plugin](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip) is more difficult.

Installing with npm (`"cytoscape-qtip": "*"`) is not the issue, and for the bundler I use a similar instruction:

```
      {
        "name": "cytoscape-qtip",
        "path": "../node_modules/cytoscape-qtip",
        "deps": ["jquery", "cytoscape", "qtip2"],
        "main": "cytoscape-qtip"
      }
```

But this doesn't work. I get following error when I try to use a simple qtip hello world: `Uncaught TypeError: this.cy.elements(...).qtip is not a function`

The reason for this, is that the cytoscape-qtip plugin hasn't initialised itself (snippet of its initialisation code):

```
  if( $ && $$ ){
    register( $$, $ );
  }

})(
  typeof jQuery !== 'undefined' ? jQuery : null,
  typeof cytoscape !== 'undefined' ? cytoscape : null
);
```

I've debugged that the 'cytoscape' parameter is null, causing the register to not execute.

I don't know how to fix the situation, because the documentation instructs me to call the `require` myself in a nested way, but I have no control over what the bundler produces.

```
CommonJS:

var cytoscape = require('cytoscape');
var cyqtip = require('cytoscape-qtip');

cyqtip( cytoscape ); // register extension

AMD:

require(['cytoscape', 'cytoscape-qtip', 'jquery'], function( cytoscape, cyqtip, jquery ){
  cyqtip( cytoscape, jquery ); // register extension
});
Note that jquery must point to a jQuery object with .qtip() registered if AMD is used.

Plain HTML/JS has the extension registered for you automatically, because no require() is needed.
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I don't want to change my entire project setup to webpack or other..

Comment: have you tried using `au import [plugin-name-here]`?

Comment: I get an 'Invalid command: import' error

Comment: Just update your au and your ready to go.